# PHP How to encode all characters with rawurlencode

Tags: php, string, utf-8, encode, urlencode

I was wondering if there is any "right out of the box" php function that can encode all the characters in the string and not only the spaces.

```
$str="Encode All Characters Not Only The Spaces In Between";

echo rawurlencode($str);
```

This Returned:

```
Encode%20All%20Characters%20Not%20Only%20The%20Spaces%20In%20Between
```

But I want to encode all the string and not just the spaces.

Comment: When something is not supposed to be encoded and you still want to encode it then you have to make your own encoding scheme for that.

Comment: No internal php command for that one ?

Comment: Just for information; why do you want to encode the entire string?

Answer (score 5):

There's no such thing, but it's easy to write:

```
function encode_all($str) {
    $hex = unpack('H*', $str);
    return preg_replace('~..~', '%$0', strtoupper($hex[1]));
}

$str = 'big ƒüßchen';
print_r(encode_all($str));
```