hide source of iframe player
i have an iframe where i put a link with a chrome extension of an .mpd player followed by the url i need to stream:
<iframe src="chrome-extension://EXTENSION-ID/pages/player.html#https://example.com/file.mpd"></iframe>
I am trying to hide the .mpd link to make it at least not instantly visible when you press F12: i tried using base64 by doint this:
<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,SOME-DATA></iframe>
but it just shows the link as plain text and doesn't load the actual extension, does anybody have any idea on how to achieve my goal?

AFAIK you can't use base64 in the src of an iframe element. It's not like an image tag

Anyway why do you want to hide this? It's just a URL. If it's accessible over HTTP then it's  public. Security by obscurity is not security.

Because i want people to watch my live stream only by my website and not watch it as people do with pirate IPTV

Then you need to build an actual streaming service with suitable safeguards in place, not just link to movie files in an iframe. Your approach is naive. Maybe start here

If this is your extension, why not just encrypt the url and decrypt it in the extension?

@shingo just more obscurity really...the source code of extensions can be read, and therefore any encryption keys and algorithms with it

the extension is just an .mpd player, not mine, i will look out for ADyson suggestion, thank you

@ADyson the OP stated the bottom line is make it at least not instantly visible when you press F12

@shingo yes but a) they then stated the ultimate goal is to prevent piracy and b) I think the original ask stems from a certain lack of awareness of how things work in the web and browsers, and what lengths people will go to in order to pirate content if they really want to. I see little point in building half-measures to create a poor solution which is still easily defeated. If you see it differently, post an answer :-)

well, by now I don't produce such high quality content to need such advanced security measures but seeing it by your perspective i see why you suggest me to use a completely different streaming service

This question has nothing to do with PHP, but the best you're going to get is URL encoding every character in the video URL (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110062/php-how-to-encode-all-characters-with-rawurlencode) and hoping the extension handles it correctly.  Doesn't really seem worth the effort though.
